# Fancybox for Images/Gallery - Add Content above image

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Using Fancybox v 2+ and want to add a simple line of content above an image/item . I can add content below and image/content without trouble.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9FE7Z/

Code:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        mouseWheel : true,
        padding: 10,
        closeBtn : false,
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            }
        },
        afterShow: function(){
            // Render tweet button
            twttr.widgets.load();

            var customContent = "<div class='customHTML'>My custom content</div>"
            $('.fancybox-inner').append(customContent);
            },
            helpers : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }  

    });
```

Basically i want the customHTML DIV to be ABOVE the image when it renders. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun ... you could use the `.before()` method inside the `afterShow` callback to switch the position of the `title` with the `content` like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // avoid unwanted flickering while changing the title to top
    openEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    prevEffect: "none",
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        var customContent = "<div class='customHTML'>My custom content</div>";
        this.title = this.title ? this.title + customContent : customContent;
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-outer").before($(".fancybox-title"));
    }
});
```

Also we may need this CSS declaration :

```
.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

... to clear the gap above the `title`.

The script works equally well for anchors with or without `title` attribute.

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dGbv/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use .prepend()  http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

```
$('.fancybox-inner').prepend(customContent);
```

Comment: Thanks, that puts the content above, but breaks the mouseWheel function (scrolling mousewheel causes image gallery to go forward/backward)

Comment: YW, I think you need rel="galleryName" for mouseWheel to work (missing from original fiddle). But JFK's solution looks more complete :)